# jQuery - Check Select Value on Refresh?

Tags: jquery, css

Please excuse the newbie code, im new.
Any coding tips are much appreciated as well of course.

Here's the Problem:

This code seems to work fine, if I first load the page, USA is selected and States is visible.
If I then select another country, the states disappear as they should...

However, if I then hit the Refresh Button, states become visible again but the country select stays what it is (not USA).

How can I protect myself from this?

```
#stateWrapper { display: block; }

#country USA is set to "selected"

$('#country').click(function(){
    var selectedValue = $("select").val();

    if(selectedValue == 'US') {
        $('#stateWrapper').attr('style', 'display: block;');            
    }else{
        $('#stateWrapper').attr('style', 'display: none;');
    }

    if(selectedValue == 'CA') {
        $('#provinceWrapper').attr('style', 'display: block;');         
    }else{
        $('#provinceWrapper').attr('style', 'display: none;');
    }
});
```

I know one workaround is to changed USA from "selected" to something else generic like "Please Select Country".
But I would prefer the convenience that the user doesnt need to select USA when 90% of the customers will be from the states.
Plus I would really like to solve a problem rather than working around it for once...

Comment: you don't need any javascript. you could add this attribute `autocomplete="off"` to your form. like this `<form method="post" id="search-form" autocomplete="off" action="/events/search">`. this will reset all values on refresh. tell me if that works, i will post separate answer. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beacause your controll is wrapped into a click event. Refreshing the page isn't a click event.

you need to use you control has a function

```
function check_country()
{
   //your code above
}
```

and the into the document ready you call

```
check_country();
```

alone and then you have to bind the function to the click event

```
$('#country').click(function(){check_country();}
```

so now your control function works both on page load and on click

at last you should have something like that:

```
function check_country()
{
    var selectedValue = $("select").val();

    if(selectedValue == 'US') {
        $('#stateWrapper').attr('style', 'display: block;');            
    }else{
        $('#stateWrapper').attr('style', 'display: none;');
    }

    if(selectedValue == 'CA') {
        $('#provinceWrapper').attr('style', 'display: block;');         
    }else{
        $('#provinceWrapper').attr('style', 'display: none;');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
   check_country();
   $('#country').click(function(){check_country();});
});
```

Comment: Awesome stuff thank you! I am going to try putting this in place now. I have a hard time with programming logic, hopefully this will help me get one step closer.

Answer (score 0):

One way of handling this would be to use the jQuery.ready() method to execute your function when the page loads as well as when the user clicks.  First pull your code into a function definition:

```
function update_states() {
   //state updating code goes here
}
```

Then add the following code to call that function when the page is loaded or refreshed:

```
$(function() {update_states();})
```

And to run it when updated as you were already doing:

```
$('#country').click(function() {update_states();})
```

Does this achieve what you were looking to do?

Comment: Yes its perfect as well, thank you. Very helpful community here I really appreciate you taking the time to help.